# How to use FTP with Tor?

Tags: onion-services, debian, vps

I've followed a couple of tutorials here, but still, I can't connect to my hidden service via FTP.

I followed a tutorial, here: [How can I anonymize my FTP traffic using the Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/how-can-i-anonymize-my-ftp-traffic-using-the-tor-network)

All successful, but currently FTP works locally in my Debian VPS (If I try to )

But doesn't work outside. Just like that tutorial said I have my second .onion address dedicated only to FTP service.

Also, for me is really unclear how should I transfer (upload and download) files from Tor Browser. I just see a list of Folders&Files.

Thank you to anyone that has patience to help me out!

Comment: I added a comment to the other post on why it will never and has never worked: The client connects, enables passive mode, the server says "connect to the data port at :127.0.0.1:2000", the client tries to use the SOCKS proxy to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 2000, IE, itself. Tor rejects the connection to a local address and the negotiation fails. This will never work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that these lines exist in the serverside torrc configuration:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ftp-service/
HiddenServicePort 21 127.0.0.1:21
```

You should also make sure you use your ftp client over the Tor network, for example, use Tor as a SOCKS proxy for your FTP client. You can use FileZilla over Tor to do this. Firstly, install FileZilla then configure Filezilla to use the SOCKS port on localhost. You can do this by selecting the "Edit" tab then clicking on "Settings". After that, expand "Connection" and click on "Generic proxy". After this, configure it like following:

```
Proxy host: 127.0.0.1
Proxy port: 9050
```

Proxy user and password doesn't matter (leave them blank). The proxy port can also be 9150 so if it doesn't work, you should try changing this first.

Comment: This won't work.

Comment: Please clarify why this won't work? Which part of this answer will cause trouble?

Comment: FTP uses a distinct connection for data traffic to be sent over which isn't accounted for.